# How can I center my image in horizontal orientation?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview, interface-builder

I have an image view that is inside of a UIScrollView so that I can pinch & zoom. My image looks fine in portrait mode, but when I go to horizontal orientation the image is not centered.

The UIScrollView is 320x460.

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 460);
    self.imageView = [[[AsyncImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    [self.imageView loadImageFromURL:self.url];

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.imageView.frame.size.width, self.imageView.frame.size.height);
    scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 4.0;
    scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 0.75;
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

}
```

And the UIScrollView delegate method

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return imageView;
}
```

**How can I center my image in horizontal orientation?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try autoresizing the scroll view:

```
scrollview.autoresizingMask = ( UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight |
                                UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth );
```